# $|d(x,A)-d(x,B)|\le d(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x\in X$ and $A,B\subseteq X$. Then
>   $$
> |d(x,A)-d(x,B)|\le d(x,y)
> $$

I know the inequality $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\le d(x,y)$ and suspect this one is stated wrong but couldn't find a counterexample. Any clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: You could just set x = y and would see obvious contradiction!

Comment: don't see how you can do anything without this without $y$ being on the left hand side as well - looks like a typo to me...  unless there is some relationship between $y$ and $A$ and $B$. --- maybe it should be $d(A,B)$ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inequality  is stated wrongly.

It’s very easy to construct counterexample. Consider $\mathbb R$ with usual metric

Now take $x=y=0$ and $A=[1,2], B=[2,3]$

Observe that above inequality doesn’t satisfy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you see a way to correct this inequality to a valid one that is usually stated and used?

Comment: One of the common inequality of this form is (as you mentioned) $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\le d(x,y)$